# Remove element from a list on KeyUp event

Tags: c#, winforms

First of all, I'm sorry if the title is lacking in information (but I'm really not sure how to explain the situation). Anyway ...

I made an application that the user can define his own shortcut key:

```cs
    static TextBox textBox;
    static List<int> keysPressed = new List<int>();

    private static void KeyCapture(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        int key = (int)(Keys)(e.KeyCode);
        //this is to prevent the same key from being repeatedly entered
        if (!keysPressed.Contains(key))
        {                
            keysPressed.Add(key);

            textBox.Text = string.Join("+", keysPressed.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

And when one of the pressed keys is released, it will be removed from the list, and finally reformulated the new combination:

```cs
    private static void KeyRelease(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        int key = (int)(Keys)(e.KeyCode);

        if (keysPressed.ToArray().Length < 2) return;

        keysPressed.Remove(key);
        textBox.Text = string.Join("+", keysPressed.ToArray());
    }
```

If I press Shift + Z, and then release Shift, the Z key is still there, as it was the last to be released. Okay, in this case it works as I expected.

The problem occurs when more than one key is pressed and when you release them at the same time, only one remains. For example: if I press Ctrl + E, and release both at the same time, only the Ctrl or E key remains (it depends on which one I release first, but it is imperceptible). But I want the keys to remain when you release them at the same time.

I tried in several ways, but to no avail.

Comment: So what is the expected behavior in the last case you described? There's no question in your question.

Comment: `HashSet` would be better for this than `List`.

Comment: @Bodacious It's just that when I release two keys at the same time, they remain. I forgot to leave that detail, I will edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I press Shift + Z, and then release Shift, the Z key is still there, as it was the last to be released. Okay, in this case it works as I expected.

As far as the computer is concerned, this is what you are always doing.  To a computer with a clock precision of a fraction of a nanosecond, they were not released at the same time.  (Ok, the keyboard has a less precise clock, but still much more precise than a human).  Even if both keys are released in the same processing cycle, your program still receives the messages in sequence from the keyboard input processing queue.  There's no way for a `WM_KEYUP` message to name multiple keys at once.

You will have to check the time between messages (e.g. with a `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` instance) in order to differentiate between "one at a time" and "simultaneous as far as the user is concerned".

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it's still not what I'm looking for. I forgot to leave a detail in the question, which is when one or more keys are released at the same time (for a human, of course), they remain on the list. I already left that detail in the question! And about the code snippet that you quoted, it's for when I hold down only one key.

Comment: I've already used the `GetKeyboardState` pinvoke method after a `Thread.Sleep ()`, to check if any key was pressed. But it still does not go as expected.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` in an event handler is a very bad idea.  I really think you need to measure the time between consecutive messages to implement your logic.  Or just ignore all released keys (remove them from your hashset but don't change the "what the hotkey is" setting on key release, on on key down).  Then if the user presses Shift+Z and releases Shift, they get Shift+Z.  If they want Z alone, they can release all keys and then press just Z.  That's a simple rule that's easy for a user to learn.

Comment: @Henrique: But right now you have an even worse bug than the one described in your question.  If you press Shift+Z and release Shift (showing "Z" alone), then release Z (still showing "Z" alone) then press "A", your program will show "A+Z".  I don't think you want that at all.  So the `if (keysPressed.ToArray().Length < 2) return` needs to go away, it is creating problems and not solving any.

Comment: If you replace the whole KeyUp handler with `keysPressed.Remove((int)e.KeyCode);` I think your users will be very happy with the result.

Comment: Good idea! It is an alternative solution. Thanks!